# Can Google Tag Manager send form data to a (Zapier) webhook?

Tags: google-tag-manager, webhooks

I'm driving Google Adwords traffic to a page with a standard lead generation form. I can not change the form or the form submission destination.

Problem: I need to send web form data to multiple destinations, and only have access to Google Analytics and Tag Manager.

Suggested Solution: Use GTM to send data via a script to a Zapier Webhook. Zapier can parse the data and I can send to several destinations.

Is this possible? If not is there another solution copy form data and send it to another web service w/o interrupting the flow of the original form destination?

Comment: Why not send from GTM directly? What are the places that need to get that data?  Advertising actors ? Maybe they already provide a tag in the GTM Template gallery for you to use, otherwise you coule also set up some custom HTML tag and call the request in JS.

Comment: GTM is just a fancy way to run Javascript. If you can trigger a zap via JS, then you can trigger it via GTM.